# How to give a value to an id created via document.createAttribute("id")

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put a span with a text inside a div.

I want to `document.queryselectorall` with the id of the span, but my span's id does not have the value "spanMerge" as its name.

```
 var para = document.createElement("div");
 var span = document.createElement("span");

 var spanAttr = document.createAttribute("id");
 spanAttr.innerHtml = "spanMerge";
 span.setAttributeNode(spanAttr);


 var tempList = document.querySelectorAll('#spanMerge');

 var textNode = document.createTextNode(e);
        span.appendChild(textNode);


 para.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: Its nothing <span id="">105020</span>

Comment: try `spanAttr.value = "spanMerge"` instead and `span.setAttributeNode(spanAttr)`

Comment: THX all it worked -> Phuz yours did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attribute doesn't have an innerHTML property, that makes no sense. Only elements have that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createAttribute for how to use attribute nodes correctly.

It would be simpler to just use [element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) though:

```js
var para = document.createElement("div");
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.setAttribute("id", "spanMerge");

var textNode = document.createTextNode("e");
span.appendChild(textNode);
para.appendChild(span);

document.body.appendChild(para);
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```